# Validate only when value is changing

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize `4.38.0` and have the custom validation for email on the User model.

The way the custom validation is constructed (see below), I need to skip the validation if the email property hasn't changed. Otherwise it halts the whole update operation (as it thinks the email address is already taken).

**How can I run validation for a property only when the value is changing?**

```
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    isEmail: {
      msg: 'Wrong email format',
    },
    notEmpty: {
      msg: 'Email has to be present',
    },
    isUnique: function(value, next) {
      User.find({
        where: {
          email: value,
          organizationId: this.organizationId,
        },
      })
        .then(function(result) {
          if (result === null) {
            return next()
          } else {
            return next(' Email address already in use')
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return next()
        })
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it's run all the time" ?

Comment: @mihai I've updated the description. The custom email validation is run on every update operation of an user instance. And I wonder if it's possible to skip that custom validation when the email value isn't changing?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with a conditional like this:

```
isUnique: function(value, next) {
  if (this.changed('email')) {
    User.find({
      where: {
        email: value,
        organizationId: this.organizationId,
      },
    })
      .then(function(result) {
        if (result === null) {
          return next()
        } else {
          return next(' Email address already in use')
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return next()
      })
  } else {
    next()
  }
},
```